# How can I calculate correlation between two sets of data within two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I will like to first create two columns and then use `LOG()` to calculate the periodic daily returns for column `Price` and column `Adjusted Close`. Thereafter using the periodic return to find the correlation between periodic daily returns calculated.

I tried

```
Combine_data['log_return'] = np.log(1 + Combine_data.pct_change)
Combine_data.head()
```

but it is not working.

```
Combine_data= pd.merge(XAU_USD,SP500, on='Date',suffixes= 
('(GOLD)','(SP500)'))
Combine_data.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
Combine_data.head()
```

This is what my output looks like:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a input dataframe.

Comment: Try this to find correlation between column A and B: `df['A'].corr(df['B'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can try that as follows:

```
ser1= (df['gold']+1).apply(np.log)
ser2= (df['silver']+1).apply(np.log)
np.corrcoef(ser1, ser2)
```

The result looks like:

```
Out[431]: 
array([[1.        , 0.30121126],
       [0.30121126, 1.        ]])
```

A correlation of 0.301 is not bad given the fact, the data is randomly generated :-)

```
Out[430]: 
          gold     silver        date
0   793.559641  19.112793  2019-08-23
1  1428.329390  17.758924  2019-08-24
2  1044.061092  17.962435  2019-08-25
3  1222.397539  17.638691  2019-08-26
4   890.945841  11.593497  2019-08-27
5  1224.616916  15.759736  2019-08-28
6  1059.684075  12.900665  2019-08-29
7  1147.011421  20.274250  2019-08-30
8   929.638993  12.244630  2019-08-31
9   515.545695  14.609073  2019-09-01
```

Comment: @rafelc: what do you mean by `no.`? Are maybe confusing `apply` with `map`?

Comment: Ah ok I see, but you're point is not correct then, I already use `np.log` and with `apply` it is not slower, but (even if by a very tiny part) faster then if I call `np.log` directly with the series as argument. I verified that on a series with 100 million of random ints.

Comment: Maybe not so much, as you think. Pandas was built on top of `numpy`, but numpy probably doesn't include a special handling for pandas objects, so maybe it does some extra checks or copies data to be on the safe side, while pandas just calls the function with the correct type and apply is not called for each element separately. You might have confused it with `map`.

Comment: Nope, I did not mistake with `map`, and even though your explanation makes sense, `series.apply(np.log)` is still a bit faster even when `np.log(z)` directly being `z`  a numpy array. That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I think we have to live with it :-) Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods to do this:

1. Use Pearsonr correlation:

   `from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
    coeff = pearsonr(x, y)[0]  # 0 is the coefficient, 1 is the p-value`
2. Use numpy correlation:

   `import numpy as np
    coeff = np.corrcoef(x,y)[0,1]`